# Associating Week number with Date Value from Table

Tags: mysql

this is my first post and I was hoping some of you could help me create a query to do the following.

I am attempting to create a Table that has date values from a Parent table, but I need those date values to be turned into the corresponding Week Number. They are 12 years worth of dates and I would appreciate it if the value returned would look like "2018.52" or something along those lines. Along with turning the dates to a week number they also need to be inserted into the second table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See Date_format in the manual. Note that you wouldn't normally store derived data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL functions `CONCAT()`, `EXTRACT()` and `WEEK()` to generate the desired string

Something like this:

`SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM the_date), '.', WEEK(the_date) FROM table`

See documentation for these date/time functions at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

Comment: Is "the_date" a subquery from the values column that I already have in the table? Or would that only be on a specified date?
When I tried your query I was getting a syntax error with the "select concat" and when I attempted to edit it to return just the extract year it was returning a 1054 error "Unknown column 'loaddate' in 'field list'
I am still extremely new to this so a bit more guidance is GREATLY appreciated :)

Comment: `the_date` is whatever you column name is. If you update your question with your tables/schema I can provide more guidance.